# TailwindCSS - How to centre caption underneath image

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to use Tailwind to get an image and its caption to be centered.

The caption sometimes could be longer than the image.  I want them to be centered along whichever of the two is longer.

The [tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content) says to use justify-center to justify items along the center of the container’s main axis.

It gives this example:

```
<div class="flex justify-center ...">
  <div>01</div>
  <div>02</div>
  <div>03</div>
</div>
```

However when I try to do something similar the items are not centered:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 justify-center">
    <div><img src="http://placeimg.com/128/128" class="h-12" /></div>
    <div class="text-xs text-gray-800">Long Caption</div>
    <div class="text-xs text-gray-800">Short</div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/EcjTbco47I

What am I doing wrong and how do I get these items centered in the containing block?

Comment: use `justify-items-center` instead

Comment: This is neater than the other answer, if you make an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`justify-items-center` will do the job.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-1 justify-items-center">
    <div><img src="http://placeimg.com/128/128" class="h-12" /></div>
    <div class="text-xs text-gray-800">Long Caption</div>
    <div class="text-xs text-gray-800">Short</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the grid is `grid-cols-1`, it will be having only one column.

So all the three `div`s occupies full width. So center each of the `div`.

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 justify-center">
    <div class="flex justify-center"><img src="http://placeimg.com/128/128" class="h-12" /></div>
    <div class="flex justify-center text-xs text-gray-800">Long Caption</div>
    <div class="flex justify-center text-xs text-gray-800">Short</div>
</div>
```